# Dist-upgrade errors on disk full, re-run shows nothing to do

Tags: upgrade

I've run apt-get update, apt-get upgrade, then apt-get dist-ipgrade, dist-upgrade ends with some errors:

```
Setting up linux-image-extra-3.13.0-139-generic (3.13.0-139.188) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-139-generic                                                 /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-139-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-139-generic /                                                boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-139-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-139-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-139-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-139-generic (--configure                                                ):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.13.0-139-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-139-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-headers-3.13.0-139 (3.13.0-139.188) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.13.0-139-generic (3.13.0-139.188) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic (3.13.0.139.148) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.13.0.139.148); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-139-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I cleaned up /boot and figured a re-run of apt-get dist-upgrade would run and complete. This time it looks like dist-upgrade thinks there is nothing to do:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I am now wondering what state the system is in. It would seem there is a partially installed kernel and dist-update can't tell it's not complete.

Comment: your boot partitions is full, apt can not add or remove kernels until you free some space.

Comment: sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: If you cleaned up /boot as you said it's probably fine.

Comment: I ran 'aptitude search ~ilinux-image' and removed the oldest kernel, there were only three listed. I'm running the middle one. I show 40M of free space in /boot. aptitude does shows;

Comment: aptitude search ~ilinux-image
i A linux-image-3.13.0-137-generic          - Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
i A linux-image-3.13.0-139-generic          - Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
i A linux-image-extra-3.13.0-137-generic            - Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
i A linux-image-extra-3.13.0-139-generic                    - Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
i   linux-image-generic                                     - Generic Linux kernel image

Comment: It's a VM, I'll make sure I have good backup image and reboot it.

Comment: ravery, re-read my post a little slower. You'll note that I said I cleaned it up. It's no longer full and dist-upgrade does not seem to think it needs to do anything. Which seems wrong as it the prior run errored.

Comment: Apt is very good at keeping track of what is complete, and what still needs to be done. Try rebooting into -139 to prove that it's properly installed.